# Delphi + ACCDB: Could not update; currently locked

Tags: delphi, ms-access-2010, ipc

I have a Delphi app that performs lengthy calculations on each record in a data set and writes results for that record to a table (one of many) in an Access 2010 ACCDB.  Since it can take hours to run, to speed things up it spawns an additional process (or more than one) to handle half the records while the main process handles the other half.  All processes and the ACCDB are local to one machine, and I’m using ADO components (TADOConnection/Table/Query).  To serialize access to the DB, I'm using a Mutex.  The flow looks like:

```
procedure AddRecord(aSourceData: TDataSet; aResults: TResults);
begin
  mutex := CreateMutex(nil, False, ‘name’);
  WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
  <find the table, t, to write to>
  <search for the record in table>
  <if found, t.Edit; else t.Append>
  <update fields in table from aSourceData and aResults>
  t.Post;  <== Error
  ReleaseMutex(mutex);
end;
```

I figured that the mutex would avoid any locking issues, since only one process would be allowed to hit the DB at a time, but I get sporadic “Could not update; currently locked” errors.  Sometimes it finishes without error, and the error can occur in either of the two process.  I've tried including an OnPostError handler and allowing up to 10 retries.  Sometimes that lets it continue, other times it still fails.

Are there some timing issues I haven’t thought of?  E.g., one process finishes its Post and ReleaseMutex calls, but the other process acquires the mutex and attempts to update the same table/record before the ACCDB lock is cleared.

Any ideas welcome.  TIA.

Comment: Are you using transactions for each process that deals with reading/writing?

Comment: No, I'm not.  Should I be?

Comment: Particularly in cases where multiple processes work on the same data set, it's always a good thing to use Transactions. This guarantees updates/fails and it *may* even solve your problem.

Comment: I added a BeginTrans/CommitTrans pair inside the Create/ReleaseMutex calls.  Unfortunately it introduced another error that I'll have to track down before I know if it helps.

Comment: Could you please add your connection code and the code to open the recordset? I think it's a thing about cursors

Comment: And *what* is the new error you got after introducing transactions? That may well lead to an answer. Please state the error.

Comment: cursors - I'm not specifying any cursor values, so I have the defaults of clUseClient and ctKeyset, if that's the info you're looking for?

Comment: transaction: When a process does not have a table for the current data record (based on an in-memory list of data-to-tablename pairs), it consults a Mapping table to see if another process has already added the table (for another record with the same data value).  If it finds the table in Mapping it adds it to its in-mem list and proceeds to use it.  The error I'm seeing is "Table ABC not found".

Comment: (continued) When I look at the MDB, Table ABC does exist.  So it looks like the CommitTrans in the process that created ABC updated the mapping record with the name "ABC" but the table itself did not appear to exist when the other process went to use it.

Comment: Through experience, I've always stuck to Client cursor for recordsets and Server cursors for the connection. Is this what you have?

Comment: Try writing the database name within square brackets liket his: [ABC] and see if there's a difference. Is the table ABC in the same database?

Comment: What more thing... I hope you're only using optimistic locking. Otherwise you may have no access to the data source when the other process is running an update

Comment: Forget mutex. The combination of locks and cursors I suggested above should be sufficient.

Comment: 1. I'm not setting the cursor type for the connection, so I have the default clUseClient.  Can try clUseServer.

2. [ABC]: The syntax was fine before adding Begin/CommitTrans, but I'll try.

3. "Otherwise you may have no access to the data source when the other process is running an update": We've now gone full circle back to the original question. With the Mutex controlling ALL access to the DB, how could there be ANY simultaneous access?

Comment: Your last statement about Mutex controlling... That's the issue IMO. It's locking the resource ABC and therefore the other threads/processes cannot read/write. My Access days are gone but I often use Lazarus + PostgreSQL and all I need is transactions. Of course I don't use ADO. I had a few old ADO projects and what I used to do was use cursors, transactions and locks like I have indicated. So as a first step, I think you should try my method without Mutex

Comment: I've tried Connection.CursorLocation=clUseServer, Table.CursorLocation=clUseClient and LockType=ltOptimistic, Begin/CommitTrans, no mutex, and things are even worse: still get "Could not update", and now "duplicate name in index" exceptions are thrown (though these do not stop processing).  Ready to throw in the towel.

"It's locking the resource ABC and therefore the other threads/processes cannot read/write." That's exactly what I want to happen! It's a feature, not a bug.

Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have the [locking type on the table or recordset](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/ADODB.TADOLockType) to ltOptomistic.  If you aren't setting it, then you're good, because it is the default for all TCustomADODataset objects.

Second, you may want to refactor your code and use transactions.  Typically, this is done with the [BeginTrans](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/ADODB.TADOConnection.BeginTrans) and [CommitTrans](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/ADODB.TADOConnection.CommitTrans) functions with your TADOConnection.

Third, you may want to rethink the whole operation.  Perhaps it would be better to construct one or more [in-memory datasets](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/a/tclientdataset.htm) and then perform batch inserts and updates to the physical database with less frequency and in serial fashion.

For example, you could create:

1. one dataset per table, or
2. one dataset for inserts and another for updates, or
3. some other scheme.

So when you reach an arbitrarily-defined threshold for the in-memory datasets, you could push the data in one bulk operation to the db.

Without access to a lot more code, your connection setup, and other environmental factors, I cannot be more specific.

Comment: Lock type: have tried both ways - didn't change anything.

Comment: Transactions: trying this now.

In-memory data: Afraid this is not possible. The app is grouping the source data on like fields and ranges.  The tables and records are created on the fly as data is encountered.  I can't have two processes creating separate tables/records for the same grouping.  Hence the mutex to grant exclusive access to one process at a time.  If I can't solve this problem, I'll have to let each process create its own DB, then merge the data later.  Doable, but more coding to do. Thanks.